# How to check that image sizes are ok or not

Tags: windows-7, images, resolution, xml

I am having many image files in one folder. Mostly there are jpg, but some png, bmp, gif, tif also (but jpg is most important if others are not possible). There are also many xml files in same folder with same names as image files are having. So there is something like this: 1.jpg, 1.xml, a.png, a.xml, 3g.bmp, 3g.xml...

All xml files are having only 1 line: `<IMGRES WIDTH="1234" HEIGHT="567" />` (of course numbers are not same).

I am looking for some easy way to check all image sizes and confirm if they are same as in xml or not. So I want output like:

`imagename, xmlwidth x xmlheight, realwidth x realheight, match/error`

Is this possible in only Windows with no other software installed?

Comment: Scripting is not a strength of Windows, solving a task like this would be a breeze in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than compare them, I'd write a script to recreate the XML files from the output of a tool such as [ImageMagick's `identify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php)

I'd start with something like

```
 for %f in (*.*) do ^
    identify -format '<IMGRES WIDTH="%w" HEIGHT="%h" />' %f% > %f%.xml
```

Then fix up the filename extension handling etc etc.

---

To do a comparison as you ask, I'd use a better scripting language (Perl in my case, but I expect many other people would use the built-in powershell)

You could use the code above but write the output to a fixed filename and then use `fc`and `if` in the for-loop to generate your desired output.

---

To do what you ask using only built-in tools I'd look at powershell.

Here is an [example from powershellcommunity.org](http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/4844/Default.aspx) which you could use as a starting point.

```
function _Get-ImageStream 
{ 
param ($File) 

$image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($File) 
$imageStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream 
$image.Save($imageStream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg) 

return $imageStream 
} 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll") 

"Name|SizeInBytes|Width|Height" >> C:\JPGInfo.txt 

$path = "C:\Images\" 
$imageFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path -Include *.jpg 

foreach ($image in $imageFiles) 
{ 
$name = $image.Name 
$length = $image.Length 
$imageStream = _Get-ImageStream -File $image.FullName 
$width = $imagestream.Width 
$height = $imageStream.Height 

"$name|$length|$width|$height" >> C:\JPGInfo.txt 
}
```